# Error: Argument 'accomplishmentController' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: html, css, angularjs, controller

http://jsfiddle.net/natecraft/jtMAq/3/

I have no idea why I'm getting this error.  Thanks for any help.

```
function accomplishmentController($scope) { 
  $scope.accomplishments = [{ name: "nate", count: 1 }];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch to "no-wrap- in head" instead of onLoad in the "Frameworks & Extensions" box in the upper left of jsfiddle.

FYI...  the reason is that using onload puts angular inside the closure of $(document).ready(function() {});  And having it in a closure leads to a variety of problems.